# I dont understand IntStream api and I dont find any explanation

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

[ from http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/ ]

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(3);
```

if "iterate" and "limit" are regular functions , how could "limit" actualy stop "iterate" from running into an infinite loop ?

nobody explains that when teaching functional programming

like if it was some sort of birth given obvious axiom I havent been told about or something :-)

quiet frustrating , like they keep saying FP makes things immutable, and I dont see what's immutable in it

they also say it's stateless, indeed, but all application needs states in the end

Comment: “I dont see what's immutable in it”—well, I don’t see anything that’s mutable in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interate` is a stream source and `limit` is an intermediate operation. We have to remember 2 important things about intermediate operations: they return a new `Stream` and they are always lazy. So `limit` will return a new `Stream` consisting of the elements of the original stream `IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)`, truncated to be no longer than maxSize `3` in length. Laziness simply means that nothing is going to happen unless you add a terminal operation such as `forEach,count,anyMathch or any other`. So with all this in mind, we can think about our code

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

as something like that [pseudo code]

```
new LimitedStream(new InfinitiveStream(0, i -> i + 2),3).forEach(print);
```

In pre Java-8 it would look more or less similar to the following

```
for (int i = 0, limit = 0; ; i += 2, limit++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (limit == 2) {
            break;
        }
}
```

an infinitive loop `for (int i = 0; i += 2)` which will stop executing after producing only 3 elements `limit = 0; ... limit ++; ... if (limit == 2) break`

Comment: so "limit" receives a stream and set its limits before "iterate" is ran...

I mean it has to follow regular java functions principles

Comment: Well, not really,  `IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).peek(i -> System.out.println("from infinitive stream: " + i)).limit(3).forEach(System.out::println);`  so `iterate` will start producing elements which later on will truncated to only 3.

Comment: it seems the stream api is some sort of inaccessible inner thing inside the JVM, ...can we create our own streams with our own functions ?

Comment: @Anton: What do you mean with “*so iterate will start producing elements which later on will truncated to only 3*”? Your own example perfectly proves that phil1234’s comment is closer to the truth, as the function is never exaluated beyond the specified limit.

Comment: @Holger, I am sorry, probably I  misunderstood stream api. Let's look closer to the previous example where we have `infinitive.peek.limit.forEach`. There is a pipeline of 3 intermediate(stream as result) and 1 final operation. When `forEach` needs to print an element it asks `limit` for the element, `limit` asks stream behind it, and so on up to the infinitiveStream. The `iterate` will provide first element, which will go into the `peek`, then `limit` and finally to `forEach`. After 3rd element `limit` will stop asking stream behind it for elements, since all allowed elements where produced.

Comment: @Holger, Yep, it looks like I was wrong.  and @phil1234 is write `limit` will set up a limit, before `iterate` will run

Comment: Correction: `iterate()` is not an intermediate operation, it is a stream source.